# Writing to the same file; not overwriting

Tags: append, threadpool, fileoutputstream

Here is my snippet.

```
File file = new File(Thread.currentThread().getName());

for(each element of the list){
createStringWriterAndPopulateDataToBeWritten
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(fo,"UTF-8");
out.write(sw.toString());
out.close();
}
```

Now say i have a `newFixedThreadPool`of size `S`; i pass this thread pool a list of work to be done. Now everytime a thread is called, it creates a file with name as the name of thread and then writes to it, but in the loop it just overwrites the file.

How can make it work to append and not overwrite, even if the Thread is called again, which can very much happen in this case since my list of Work to the thread pool is pretty long.

Note:Each element of the list of jobs passed to the ThreadPool is also a list and that is why there a for loop in the snippet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but in the loop it just overwrites the file.

Well yes - you're creating the `FileOutputStream` *in the loop*. If you create the `FileOutputStream` (and the `OutputStreamWriter`) *before* the loop, then just do the writing in the loop, it will create a single file for the whole operation.

Note that the `close` call should be in a `finally` block so you close the writer even if the code throws an exception.

If you *also* need to append to the file if this code is called again, just change this:

```
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

to

```
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

The second argument, as per [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29), states whether to append (true) or overwrite (false).

Comment: so even if i create fileOutputStream in the loop and keep the second argument true; it should work ehh?
Not a good practice, but still it will work right?

Comment: because calling the same code again will be equivalent to calling the fileoutputStream inside the loop? Thanks

Comment: @Kraken: It would work, but be horribly inefficient. It would be *far* cleaner to open the file once, write everything, then close it. Reopen it to append data when you need to, but not on each iteration of the loop when you *know* you're going to write more.

Comment: shall the close statement be in the loop too, would i want to close it each time for the loop?

Comment: if it is outside the loop, how do i add a finally clause there, is not it supposed to be with a try catch only?

Comment: @Kraken: You don't need a `catch` block, but yes, you'll need a `try` block. You should *always* be using a try/finally statement when dealing with files and similar "closable" resources. (Or if you're using Java 7, you can use a try-with-resources statement.)